# woocommerce - product id getting changed within same template file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on customizing woocommerce templates in my plugin and loading the same from plugin directory. Now I am facing a wierd problem in `content-single-product.php`. The problem is the `product_id` is getting changed after the line `do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary');` in this template file. I am struggling with this from few days and not able to find where the issue is. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

For Example:

```
        <div class="summary entry-summary">
        <?php
        /**
        * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
        *
        * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
        * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
        * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
        * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
        * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
        * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
        * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
        */
        the_ID();//displaying 4829
        do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary');
        the_ID();//displaying 4822
        ?>

    </div>
```

**Update:**

I am displaying the product id just to debug the atual issue I am facing. By checking the product ids I understood that the issue is somewhere around the line 'do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary');'. The actual issue faced was that I am seeing same product description in product tabs of all the products uploaded by same author (prior to this I have added Author to 'product' post_type). And so I want to got further deep to solve this issue.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: The real id is `4829` and yes you are right that '4822' belongs to product shown in related products section i.e., `woocommerce_output_related_products`. Any Idea how to resovle this conflict?

Comment: This doesn't really help… See in that test web site, I have just output the Product ID before and after the concerned hook, and I don't get this problem: http://www.cbleu.net/sites/tie/product/ship-your-idea/ … So you have have certainly made some customizations that are responsible of your problem.

Comment: Sorry I missed to add that I did few customizations, so I might have messed  up with the code somewhere. Let me check back the customizations and update you